# How do I transform a ray correctly?

Tags: c, opengl, glm-math

How can I transform this ray, So that it is in front of the square

I'm trying to cast a ray from the player(small square).
The yellow part is the front end of the player
The ray should stop if it hits a wall(green square).
This works correctly, but the position of the ray is incorrect

The ray should be in front of the player(near the yellow part)
[image]

**Calculating the Ray's Position and Drawing it**

```c
int mx, my, mp, dof;
float rayX, rayY, rayAngle, xOffset, yOffset;

const int maxRayCount = 1, maxDOF = 8;

rayAngle = playerAngle;

for(int rayCount = 0; rayCount < maxRayCount; rayCount++)
{
    // Check for Horizontal Lines
    dof = 0;
    float aTan = -1/tan(rayAngle);
    
    if(rayAngle > glm_rad(180)) // looking down
    {
        rayY = (((int)playerPos[1] >> 6) << 6) - 0.0001f;
        rayX = (playerPos[1] - rayY) * aTan + playerPos[0];
        
        yOffset = -mapSize;
        xOffset = -yOffset * aTan;
    }
    
    if(rayAngle < glm_rad(180)) // looking up
    {
        rayY = (((int)playerPos[1] >> 6) << 6) + mapSize;
        rayX = (playerPos[1] - rayY) * aTan + playerPos[0];
        
        yOffset = mapSize;
        xOffset = -yOffset * aTan;
    }
    
    if(rayAngle == 0 || rayAngle == glm_rad(180))
    {
        rayX = playerPos[0];
        rayY = playerPos[1];
        
        dof = maxDOF;
    }
    
    while(dof < maxDOF)
    {
        mx = (int)(rayX) >> 6;
        my = (int)(rayY) >> 6;
        
        mp = (mapY - my - 1) * mapX + mx;
        
        if(mp > 0 && mp < mapSize && map[mp] == 1) // hit
        {
            dof = maxDOF;
        }
        else
        {
            rayX += xOffset;
            rayY += yOffset;
            
            dof += 1;
        }
    }

    // Drawing the Ray
    rayVertices[0] = (Vertex){{playerPos[0], playerPos[1], 0.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}};
    rayVertices[1] = (Vertex){{rayX, rayY, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}};

    mat4 rayTransform;
    glm_mat4_identity(rayTransform);

    mat4 mvp;
    glm_mat4_mulN((mat4* []){&projectionMatrix, &viewMatrix, &rayTransform}, 3, mvp);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(rayShaderProgram, "mvp"), 1, GL_FALSE, (float*)mvp);

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(rayVertices), rayVertices);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

**Calculating the Player's Position and using it**

```c
glm_vec2_add(playerPos, (vec2){cos(playerAngle), sin(playerAngle)}, playerPos);

glm_translate(playerTransform, playerPos);
glm_rotate(playerTransform, playerAngle, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
```

I transform the player, but not the ray.
How do I transform the ray?

Comment: Assuming that the red dot is the "player", what is the front of the player? It's always a good idea to add a little something that shows the front.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: At least the angle seems to be correct (unless it's 180 degrees off), and it's just a positioning problem. Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to check the position of the starting and ending point of the ray? Have you done the calculations using pen and paper?

Comment: yes, the angle is correct. I feel like the position of the ray is incorrect because I am not transforming the ray using a transform matrix. But I don't know how should I do it.

Comment: you transform ray position with your 4x4 matrix using `(x,y,z,1.0)` and ray direction using `(x,y,z,0.0)`